# OS X Enclosing folder shortcut?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-snow-leopard, finder

This may have been asked before, but I'm wondering whether there is a shortcut for navigating to the enclosing folder in OS X (Snow Leopard)?

I find navigating Finder particularly frustrating since it's hard navigating back to the enclosing folder (especially when you jump to a folder and realize the back button is disabled)...

I'm hoping for something other than Command+Up, since that's the key combination I use to navigate Spaces.

Comment: Just curious, why don't you use the default Ctrl+Arrow shortcuts for spaces, leaving Cmd+Arrow shortcuts for their default Finder navigation meanings?

Comment: Really? I thought Command+Arrow was default. Hmmm, I'm probably wrong then, but I'm too used to Command+Arrow now to change it.

Comment: oh. @Spiff I know now. "Command" is on both sides of the keyboard and I like using just one hand to change spaces instead of two. With Ctrl+Arrow you have to have one hand on the Ctrl key and another on the arrow keys... I prefer using just one hand when browsing the internet etc. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be disappointing for your application, but it's Command+Up by default, however you can easily create a keyboard shortcut for that inside your "System Preferences"

Just click the + button, then select Finder.app in the pulldown menu, type "Enclosing Folder" in the Menu Title field and create whatever shortcut you want.

But by default, it's Command+up

Comment: Nice suggestion. I shall do that.